# Primefaces video using StreamedContent - cannot navigate within video player

Tags: jsf, video, primefaces, video-streaming

We are using Primefaces 12, Java 11, Spring 5.3.21, Tomcat 9.

We store videos in Azure cloud storage and we want to make them available to view within our application. The azure video url contains a token/key we don't want visible to our users, so I am attempting to use Primefacs' p:video tag and using the StreamedContent object.  We're noticing when we stream video using StreamedContent, within the Primefaces video player, if the video is 10 minutes long and we try to jump to minute 5 using the progress bar/button, it will not work (the video just keeps playing) and the progress bar/button just jumps right back to where the video is currently playing.

Our tag usage looks like this:

```
<p:video value="#{mediaPlayerBean.video}" controls="true" width="100%" player="mp4" cache="false"/>
```

Our backing bean looks like this:

```
@Component
@Scope("request")
public class MediaPlayerBean {

   public MediaPlayerBean() {

   }

   private StreamedContent video;

   public StreamedContent getImage() {
      if(video == null) {
         fileLink();
      }
      return video;
   }
   
   public void fileLink()  {
         String url = (method call to get azure video url as a string...)

         int contentLength = (calls method to get content length...)

         InputStream inputStream = new URL(url).openStream();

         video = DefaultStreamedContent.builder()
               .contentLength(contentLength)
               //.contentEncoding() <- could setting this help? What would be an appropriate value?
               .contentType("video/mp4")
               .stream(()->inputStream)
               .build();

   }

}
```

I've compared playing the video through the primefaces p:video widget using StreamedContent and using a URL and looking in the Browsers networking tab I noticed some differences:

Direct URL :

- The status code is 206 Partial Content
- Response Headers lists Accept-Ranges as bytes, connection = keep-alive

StreamedContent :

- The status code is 200
- Response Headers does not list accept ranges or connection keep alive.
- lists cache-control as no-cache

StreamedContent

[image]

Direct URL

[image]

I know that DefaultStreamedContent provides the method contentEncoding(), but I have no idea what valid values are for mp4 video files. I also know DefaultStreamedContent provides a write() method, but I'm not sure how to implement that correctly. I tried writing the inputstream but was running into the same results as using stream (cannot jump around in the video to different time positions).

If using the .write() method is the way to go, an example would be greatly appreciated.

This might be a rare use case since most probably just use the URL directly? :(

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Mime type should be `video/mp4` or `application/mp4`  I wonder if this is just a flaw in StreamedContent and the video player.